# With neo4j's Cypher how can I find disconnected node groups with a maximum group diameter of 3

Tags: neo4j, cypher, networkx

In neo4j I have a graph with disconnected groups (i.e. the nodes of
one group have no links to any nodes in another group).

Most of the nodes in the build one large group with many links and a
large *group diameter*. (As *group diameter* I describe the [graph
diameter](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDiameter.html) of the
group as a separate graph.) However I know there are a few other
groups of nodes in the total graph with a group diameter of only **3**.

Here a visualisation of a sample network:

[image: Graph with disconnected groups]

This graph has a large group (in blue) with diameter 11 and two small groups (in green) with diameter 3.

How can I find these smaller groups with a Cypher query?

Comment: Please give an example of your graph, or better create a neo4j console http://console.neo4j.org/

Comment: @logisima Just updated the question with a better description and an image of a  sample graph.

Answer (score 0):

To find those clusters, it's an heavy operation ...

For each node, you need to :

- search if a path with a length of 4 exists
- if it doesn't exist, to make a graph traversal with a max depth of 3.

With that you will find the cluster for each node.

Instead of doing that by yourself, I recoomend you to take a look at the [graph-algo](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-graph-algorithms) plugin, you will find some algo to performs community detection.